# Is it possible to estimate a substance's water solubility from data like the substance's partition coefficient, dissociation constants, etc.?

Tags: solvents, theoretical-chemistry, solubility

If it is possible, how would you estimate a compound's water solubility from data like its partition coefficient, $ \log P $, its dissociation constant, $pK_a $, its molar mass, etc.?

Comment: I think it can be done, but first you have to have model, so you can gather your data via http://www.vcclab.org/lab/alogps/ -> lots of compounds -> lots of descriptors (as you mentioned) -> output logS (solubility) -> heuristic(?) model (maybe ANN would be useful?) -> then input data -> output (predicted solubility)

Comment: Moreover similar things have been done at http://onschallenge.wikispaces.com/Predictive+Solubility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could certainly be *estimated* from those properties, the structure, etc.  A lot of companies have developed proprietary algorithms for things like that:  solubility, diffusion coefficient, polarity.... (For example of a company, see "ChemAxon")

The water solubility for many chemicals is already known, though.  Search for a chemical [ChemSpider](https://www.chemspider.com/), and look under the "Properties" tag.

They've even got an API, in case you're interested in using water solubility in an app.